# Use of variables global and variables of class in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a question about use of global variables and variables of class using `class var`.

Declaring variables in class with `class var`:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

type
  TClass = class
  public
    class var ObjectList: TObjectList
  end;

implementation
end.
```

Declaring global variables:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

var
  ObjectList: TObjectList

implementation
end.
```

How does the compiler allocate memory for these two variables?

Comment: Worth to mention what in both cases `ObjectList` pointer will reside in DATA segment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These variables are implemented in exactly the same way. The `class var` is implemented as a global variable. That is there is a single instance of the variable in the module, allocated statically.

The only difference is that the `class var` is in a different scope, and you can use visibility protection specifiers like `private` to limit access to the variable.

Comment: And to completely answer his question (`how does the compiler allocate memory for these two variables?`), memory allocation for both variables would be in the static data segment.  For reference types only the pointer is allocated in the data segment and object space is allocated dynamically at runtime in the usual way (on the heap).

Comment: I prefer to avoid talking about platform specific implementation details here. There's a single instance of the variable in the module. That's the mental memory model that is needed.

Comment: Fair enough, but his specific question was how memory was allocated for these variables.  I think a complete answer should at least address that question, even if it provides an open answer (ie : "it depends on the platform").

Comment: @J... Actually it was me that asked that part of the question. Look at the edits. I think he's really just wondering what the difference is between these options. And what counts is not data segments, but that there is a single instance. In my view.